# Python Image / Shape recognition task

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I am working with images similar to these examples below:

[image: Image 1]

As in the above image, the images will always be a hexagon. Within each hexagon, there will be a shape which is connected to one some of the edges.

I want to be able to grab this image and determine the shapes inside this.

To do this, I want to store the objects in an array structure like this:

[1,1,1,1,1,1]
where the values are represented by whether or not the shape connects to these corresponding edges of the hexagon:

[Top, Top Left, Bottom Left, Bottom, Bottom Right, Top Right] (going clockwise)

Another example of the image would be:

[image: Image 2]

This image would be represented by the array [0,1,0,1,0,0].

In order to create this array, I am checking the pixel at each of the points on the images shown by a red dot to see if the color is blue. This works fine for these types of shapes.

The complication for this task arises is that the hexagon may contain 2 separate shapes, which I want to store the array for each shape in the hexagon.

An example would be like below:

[image: Image 3]

As can be seen with this image, the hexagon can have 2 shapes, although the 2 shapes will never share the same edge of the hexagon.

I would want to represent this as:

Shape 1: [0,1,0,0,1,0]
Shape 2: [1,0,0,1,0,0]

If I was to use my existing algorithm, I would just discern it as: [1,1,0,1,1,0] which is not what I am wanting to do.

How can I discern between these shapes?

Kind Regards,

Comment: How would you be able to distinguish that the final example is 2 shapes and not 3?

Comment: You could do a flood fill of the blue shape starting at the red dot, and check which other red dots you can reach. (Or go from red dot straight to the center and then straight to other red dots, instead of doing a full flood fill.) That would tell you that the top side is connected to the bottom side in your last example. You would then have to assume that the bottom left and top right are connected to each other.

Comment: The images will only have 1 or 2 shapes in the hexagon, not 3. @m69 that is a pretty good idea. I will have a look at what PIL and cv2 have built-in for that functionality. I am open to other ideas too :)